# Expandable mini version of sidenav in MaterializeCSS

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I want to create a sidenav like in images (described on [material.io](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior) under “mini variant”), but in (HTML, CSS and) MaterializeCSS. How can it be done?

Mini drawer:[image: mini drawer]

Expanded drawer:[image: expanded]

Comment: Any luck achieving it? Because this seems to be a good UI instead of the completely closing side nav. Kindly share.